# document.documentElement.outerHTML.length is not equal with doc type in chrome network tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, devtools, content-length, outerhtml

I want to get the document size, when the page is ready. (just in time after server request).

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {

          var pageSizelenght = document.documentElement.outerHTML.length;        

        //});
```

This does not give me the exact result with chrome dev-tools document type file in network section.

[image]

F.e the dcoument size is shown as 1.5 MB, but in the code it returns 1.8MB  with
document.documentElement.outerHTML.length

If it is not proper way, how can I get the document size listed in network section?
If you can help me, so much appreciated.

Comment: `outerHTML` is recreating the HTML from the DOM. There can be lots of differences in spacing from the original HTML file, so the lengths will be different.

Comment: The page size in the developer tab will not include loaded CSS and JavaScript, but doing what your code is doing *will* include that content. (Well, it might, at least.)

Comment: @ Barmar @ Pointy  thanks for answers, The page size in the developer tab aslo includes loaded CSS and JavaScripts, just correction.. so How can I get this size properly, have any idea?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have any access to the original HTML source. Why do you need this?

Comment: to get page size. I need to get html content size which is listed on network section as doucment type.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said in comments, the `outerHTML` is a serialization of the DOM representation after parsing of the original markup. This may be completely different than the original markup and will most likely not match in size at all:

```js
const markup = "<!doctype html><div><p><div>foo";
// DOMParser helps parsing markup into a DOM tree, like loading an HTML page does
const doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(markup, "text/html");
const serialized = doc.documentElement.outerHTML;
console.log({ serialized });
console.log({ markup: markup.length, serialized: serialized.length });
```

---

To get the size of the original markup you can call the `performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")` method, which will return an array of [`PerformanceNavigationTiming`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming) objects, where you'll find the one of the initial document (generally at the first position).
These `PerformanceNavigationTiming` objects have fields that let you know the decoded-size of the resource, its coded-size (when compressed over the wire), and its transferred-size (can vary if cached).

Unfortunately, this API doesn't work well for iframes (*moreover the ones that are fetched through POST requests like StackSnippets*), so I have to outsource the live demo to [this Glitch project](https://measure-docs-size.glitch.me/).

The main source is:

```js
const entry = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")
  // That will probably be the first here,
  // but it might be better to check for the actual 'name' of the entry
  .find(({name}) => name === location.href);

const {
  decodedBodySize,
  encodedBodySize,
  transferSize
} = entry;
log({
  decodedBodySize: bToKB(decodedBodySize),
  encodedBodySize: bToKB(encodedBodySize),
  transferSize: bToKB(transferSize)
});

function bToKB(b) { return (Math.round(b / 1024 * 100) / 100) + " KB"; }
```

Comment: You are amazing!! But just  orginal decodedBodySize is enough.  console.log(entry); I can see the size is the same with listed document in network tab
  -This is the size of documet on network tab section. We dont need to convert byte to kb.. (even if we need , 1kb is 1000 byte:) ,not 1024 ) Thanks so so much  .

Comment: Chrome and Firefox dev-tools do report in KiB even though they write "KB". And it does report all three decoded, encoded, and transfer sizes. It depends where you look at.